Data Lost Between Routes in Vue.js on Refresh
I'm working on a Vue.js application using Vue Router and Axios to fetch user data. I have two pages: /dashboard and /dashboard/me. The data for the /dashboard page is successfully loaded and displayed, even after refreshing. However, when I navigate to /dashboard/me and refresh the page, I lose the data from Dashboard components (Dashboard is a wrapper for all children routes), and the request results in a 304 Not Modified status code.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Vue Router setup: The routes are defined as follows:
const routes: RouteRecordRaw[] = [
    {
        path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard, name: 'dashboard',
        children: [{ path: 'me', name: 'me', component: AboutMePage }],
    },
];

I initially had the me route defined as path: 'me' (relative), but when I change it to path: '/me' (absolute), the page works correctly on refresh, but the issue is that now the route becomes /dashboard and /me instead of /dashboard/me.

Axios request: I’m using Axios to fetch data, and it works fine on the /dashboard route. On the /dashboard/me route, however, when I refresh the page, I get a 304 Not Modified response, which causes the data to be lost.

The request code is as follows:

export const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'v1/',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',   // Disable cache
        // 'Pragma': 'no-cache',           // HTTP 1.0 compatibility
        // 'Expires': '0',                 // Ensures cache is expired
    }
})

The refetch function is also used to refresh the data.
Proxy configuration in Vite: I have configured a proxy in my vite.config.ts file to redirect requests to the backend server.
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/v1': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3001/',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        configure: (proxy, _options) => {
          proxy.on('error', (err, _req, _res) => {
            console.log('proxy error', err);
          });
          proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, _res) => {
            console.log('Sending Request to the Target:', req.method, req.url);
          });
          proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, _res) => {
            console.log('Received Response from the Target:', proxyRes.statusCode, req.url);
          });
        },
      }
    }
  }
})


Problem:

When I refresh the /dashboard/me page, I get an empty response and the data is lost.
The network response shows 304 Not Modified, but on the /dashboard page, it works fine and I get the correct data.
What I’ve tried:

Changing the route path from relative ('me') to absolute ('/me'), which made the page work, but broke the URL structure.
Using Cache-Control: no-cache headers in Axios, but still getting the 304 response.
Clearing the browser cache and testing in incognito mode, but the issue persists.
Questions:

Why does changing the route path ('me' to '/me') affect the behavior of the data fetching?
Why does the request for /dashboard work fine, but /dashboard/me loses the data upon page refresh?
How can I fix the issue and ensure that I always fetch fresh data without altering the URL structure?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Do you see the payload coming in the network request on the me route?

@kissu I get only 200 code for that api and in the response is html page not real data. But if i navigate back to dashboard route then the api returns the correct data.

@kissu I don't understand why the request works when i am on Dashboard page but not on AboutMe page (dashboard/me)

Maybe try with path: '/me' on the route config? Double-checking that route might be nice with the Vue devtools. I am not sure if the proxy is maybe messing up a few things? Try to use Postman (or alike) to be sure that all of this is not a backend issue. It should send you a JSON response consistently. That might help us narrow down where the issue is coming from. Otherwise yes, the rest of the network tab is the way to go for more in-depth troubleshooting.

@kissu,  the weirdest thing is that /me works, but i need to keep the structure of path like: dashboard/me, but changing to /me i get only /me

If you don't specifically rely on parent/children for view component logic, the use of path: 'dashboard/me' instead of children could be a proper workaround if it's router bug. The question doesn't contain useGetUserQuery, which may be relevant since you have problems with data fetching.  What you describe could be possible if you use relative urls for fetch.  At least make sure that the request is made with correct url when you receive html response. Otherwise, please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be debugged

@EstusFlask, i need to rely on parent route. Also i updated the question with the missing code. Could you please take a look?

@Asking how is axiosInstance created? Specifically baseURL

@EstusFlask, i added an update for the question that contains the code.

That a request works when made on top-level route but fails on nested one with HTML response suggests that a possible cause is that it was made to wrong URL. This should be seen in network requests in dev tools.
This is a common problem for the applications that use relative URLs for the requests and don't have correctly set <base>.
It's virtually never desirable to make API requests to relative path. Since Axios is used, it should be baseURL: '/v1/ instead of baseURL: 'v1/.
